# How to merge two rows in spark dataframe to get null values in output

Tags: apache-spark

I have multiple rows in spark dataframe which i want to merge as below

present dataframe rows

```
+----+------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+
| id | name | senior1 | senior2 | senior3 | date               |
+----+------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+
|  1 | abc  | null    | pqr     | man     | 2020-03-12 00:00:0 |
|  1 | abc  | def     | null    | man     | 2020-03-12 00:00:0 |
+----+------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+
```

Expected Output

```
+----+------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+
| id | name | senior1 | senior2 | senior3 | date               |
+----+------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+
|  1 | abc  | null    | null    | man     | 2020-03-12 00:00:0 |
+----+------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+
```

One thing that i have tried is to replace null with a min value and then group. But this is a very long process. Can you please suggest me some better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

Again it is similar to what you are trying with `groupBy`

```
df.show(false)

+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+
|id |name|senior1|senior2|senior3|date             |
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+
|1  |abc |null   |pqr    |man    |2020-03-1200:00:0|
|1  |abc |def    |null   |man    |2020-03-1200:00:0|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+

val cols = df.columns.diff(List("id")).toList

val res = df.groupBy("id").agg( when(size(array_intersect(array(lit("null")), collect_list(col(cols.head)))) > 0, null).otherwise(first(cols.head)).as(cols.head),
  cols.tail.map(c => when(size(array_intersect(array(lit("null")),collect_list(col(c)))) > 0, null).otherwise(first(col(c))).as(c)):_*)


res.show(false)

+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+
|id |name|senior1|senior2|senior3|date             |
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+
|1  |abc |null   |null   |man    |2020-03-1200:00:0|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+
```

Note: Make sure NULL should be String like "null".

> Update: When null as object

//Null as object

```
val res = df.groupBy("id").agg( when(size(array_intersect(array(lit(null)), flatten(collect_list(array(col(cols.head)))))) > 0, null).otherwise(first(cols.head)).as(cols.head),
  cols.tail.map(c => when(size(array_intersect(array(lit(null)),flatten(collect_list(array(col(c)))))) > 0, null).otherwise(first(col(c))).as(c)):_*)

+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+
|id |name|senior1|senior2|senior3|date             |
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+
|1  |abc |null   |null   |man    |2020-03-1200:00:0|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+
```

Comment: You welcome! you can up vote and accept the answer :)

Comment: Sathiyan, in case I have different dates in the above scenario and i want to get the max among those. Can you please suggest me here

Answer (score 1):

You achieve in **PySpark** by creating a **UDF** like below,

```
    schema = StructType([StructField("id", StringType(), True),
                              StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                              StructField("senior1", StringType(), True),
                              StructField("senior2", StringType(), True),
                              StructField("senior3", StringType(), True),
                              StructField("date", StringType(), True)])
    
    df = spark.createDataFrame([('1', 'abc', None, 'pqr', 'man', '2020-03-12 00:00:0'), ('1', 'abc', 'def', None, 'man', '2020-03-12 00:00:0')],
                               schema=schema)
    
    df.show()

    # below code is to check whether '-1' value found or not if found return None

    def null_check(x):
        for i in x:
            if i == '-1':
               return None
        return ','.join(x)
    
    
    find_null = F.udf(null_check)

   # replace the null value with '-1'

    df = df.groupBy('id', 'name', 'date').agg(
        find_null(F.collect_set(F.when(F.col("senior1").isNull(), '-1').otherwise(F.col("senior1")))).alias('senior1'),
        find_null(F.collect_set(F.when(F.col("senior2").isNull(), '-1').otherwise(F.col("senior2")))).alias('senior2'),
        find_null(F.collect_set(F.when(F.col("senior3").isNull(), '-1').otherwise(F.col("senior3")))).alias('senior3')).select(
            'id', 'name', 'senior1','senior2','senior3','date')
    
    df.show()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+------------------+
| id|name|senior1|senior2|senior3|              date|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+------------------+
|  1| abc|   null|    pqr|    man|2020-03-12 00:00:0|
|  1| abc|    def|   null|    man|2020-03-12 00:00:0|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+------------------+

+---+----+-------+-------+-------+------------------+
| id|name|senior1|senior2|senior3|              date|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+------------------+
|  1| abc|   null|   null|    man|2020-03-12 00:00:0|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to make use of the fact that the count function does not count null values. Try this :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
tst=sqlContext.createDataFrame([(2,None,3),(None,102,100),(4,None,5),(9,None,103),(2,11,12),(4,13,14)],schema=['col1','col2','col3'])
#%
expr = [F.when(F.count(F.col(coln))==F.count('*'),F.min(coln)).alias(coln) for coln in tst.columns]
tst_res = tst.select(*expr)
```

results:

```
tst_res.show()
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|null|null|   3|
+----+----+----+
```

But, i dont find any issue in how you are doing now, replace and group. can you post how you are trying and what difficulty you are facing?

Comment: Thanks Raghu and Saurabh, But i am using spark scala and not pyspark. And also I have to do this without using a UDF.

Comment: @user12976942 - you're welcome. Try if you can take over the concept from this answer to scala. In future, it would be great if you could mention that you are looking for solutions in scala in your title or questions.. good luck :-)